# My ViewModel has null values when my View is loaded, how to delay loading of the View until the ViewModel populates the data?

Tags: android, android-fragments, mvvm

This is my Fragment xml:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>
    <variable
        name="viewModel"
        type="UserProfileViewModel" />
</data>

<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/image_user_avatar"
     app:userAvatarUrl="@{viewModel.currentUser.avatarUrl}" />
```

It has a viewModel variable, which is the following Java class:

```
public class UserProfileViewModel extends BaseViewModel {

private User mCurrentUser;

public void setSignedInUser(User signedInUser) {
    mCurrentUser = signedInUser;
}

public User getCurrentUser() { return mCurrentUser; }
```

In my Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mUserId = getArguments().getString(Strings.KEY_USER_ID);
    }
    mViewModel = UserProfileViewModel.getInstance();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_user_profile, container, false);
    mBinding.setViewModel(mViewModel);
    mBinding.buttonSignOut.setOnClickListener((View view) -> signOutUser());
    mBinding.fragmentUserProfileSwipeRefreshContainer.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    return mBinding.getRoot();
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getUserProfile();
}

public void getUserProfile() {
    GetUserProfileRequest request = new GetUserProfileRequest(mUserId);
    mGetUserProfileDisposable = mViewModel
            .getUserProfile(request)
            .doOnSubscribe(__ -> mBinding.fragmentUserProfileSwipeRefreshContainer.setRefreshing(true))
            .doOnError((Throwable ex) -> mBinding.fragmentUserProfileSwipeRefreshContainer.setRefreshing(false))
            .subscribe((Response<GetUserProfileResponseBody> response) -> {
                if (response.body() != null) {
// this user object has the avatarUrl field needed in the xml                       
                    mViewModel.setSignedInUser(response.body().getSignedInUser());
                }
            }, (Throwable ex) -> {
            });
}
```

By the time setSignedInUser is called, the Fragment has already been loaded, and viewModel variable in XML has not yet been populated, so the avatarUrl is null, so no image is loaded. How do I prevent this?

Comment: View must be loaded before populating the data. What you can do is hide the view until the data is loaded. hide View > Show  progress indicator > Load data > hide progress indicator > show View

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if (viewModel!= null) {

} else {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
```

Comment: could you explain?